# PHP header('Location : /xyz/') returns HTML code instead of redirecting to 'xyz/'

Tags: php, ajax, header

I am using ajax to insert some data into the DB. If the data is inserted into the DB successfully, I want to redirect to another page.

Here is my code:

```
if (DB::insertRegistrationUser($email, $password, $subscribe)) {
                header('Location: /xyz/');
}
```

In the network tab, I see that the page was requested and delivered with 200 OK, but the current page does not redirect to the new page '/xyz/'.

Im sure its something minor, but could someone help me out here. Thanks

Comment: You have to detect a successful ajax completion then redirect on the main page with js. You can't have php do it.

Comment: "current page"... the one that requested the redirect? If the header was working, you'd have gotten a 301 code instead.

Comment: Return a true/false from the AJAX call, then use JS to change the current window.location to a url of your choosing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to detect a successful ajax completion then redirect on the main page with javascript. You can't have php do it. Example with Jquery

```
$.post('/your/url',data,function(returned_url){
    window.location = returned_url;
});
```

Then in the php:

```
if (DB::insertRegistrationUser($email, $password, $subscribe)) {
    echo '/xyz/';
    die();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

- header is php is server side coding
- ajax is javascript is client side coding

EITHER you change your server code to through the header statement

OR you change your client side code to have something javascripty like in there (instead the header statement) - eg:

```
window.location.href="/xyz/";
```